# Is the classic alpine combined used as a skiing discipline or now all drive super combined?

Tags: skiing

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_skiing_combined) it is said that, Alpine combined is consisting of one run of Downhill and two runs of Slalom, while its variation Super Combined, can be Downhill/SuperG, plus one run of Slalom. From the past years I only see a Super Combined discipline, right? Is the classic Alpine combined used at all? I guess no, cause now it is believed that, even with one run of Slalom, the technical skiers have an advantage, therefore is bigger with two run of Slalom.

I'm also one of the guys, who contribute to the 2016 [Alpine Skiing World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Alpine_Skiing_World_Cup) Wikipedia page, and in the Men's section I see that there are two Alpine Combined events, and only the third one is marked as Super Combined. I guess they are all Super Combined and this is a little bit unclear. I want to fix it, but I want to be sure about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the result pages linked:

- [Kitzbuehel](https://data.fis-ski.com/dynamic/results.html?sector=AL&raceid=82804)
- [Wengen](https://data.fis-ski.com/dynamic/results.html?sector=AL&raceid=82796)

There are only two runs in each of these events, and the total time is about expected for one short downhill and one slalom, which suggests it is the super combined.

Looking in the rules, what is often is called super combined is named Alpine combined [in the rules](http://www.fis-ski.com/inside-fis/document-library/alpine-skiing/index.html#deeplink=rules). The rules also have something called classic combined in it, but when searching for events I can only find Alpine combined, not classic combined.